# gsub character string which contains special characters

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am new to R, although I can see variations of my question have been asked multiple times I just cannot seem to find any variation of gsub that just removes the special characters. In effect I have hit a brick wall.

I have a dataframe contraining 73 variables. Variable 2, AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER, is character based.

An example of one of the fields in this column is thus: `<U+00A0>CUB00716`

All I need is to remove the following characters, < + >

I have gone through around 30 different gsub, dplyr and regex combinations following examples from the internet and not a single one has done anything to remove any of those characters.

I'm aware that + is class as an escape character and therefore requires a \ or an argument of fixed=TRUE or for the + to be in brackets [].

Examples of some of the gsub commands I have tried are below.

```
clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER <- gsub('\\+', '', clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER)

clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER <- gsub('[+]', '', clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER)

require(dplyr)
clean <- clean %>%
mutate_all(funs(gsub("\\<\\>\\+", "", .)))
```

I'm sure I am missing something that will be glaringly obvious to most of the people on this forum, but for the life of me I cannot see why it will not just remove the + character.

Comment: `gsub('[your_characters_to_match]+', '', vector)` should be fine. Do you have any string examples?

Comment: Yes, `"[<+>]+"` for the pattern should remove all of those. Using brackets, you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: Sorry, had not realised that the sybols were stripped from my pasted example. "<U+00A0>CUB00716" is one example.

Am just trying your suggestions now, figured it would be a syntax issue on my part.

Comment: So I have tried the following code: clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER <- gsub('[<+>]+', '', clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER)

However is still leaves the example in place, row 62220 is "<U+00A0>CUB00716" and row 75678 is "<U+00A0>31063"

Cannot work out why these symbols refuse to die. 

Structure of the dataframe clean shows variable 2 as a chr

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mako212 I've tried using your method like this `clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER <- gsub('[<+>]+', "", clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER)`

But the column remains as it was, the characters of <+> remain.

Is the syntax of my gsub incorrect?

Comment: Those are most probably Unicode chars, not literal `<`, `+` and `>` chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I could kiss you. I have struggled for 3 hours trying regex, gsub and goodness knows what else.

Yes, they are unicode. I used iconv and they are gone.

It was worth the -1 down vote from some mean spirited individual.

Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

This removes the 3 indicated characters:

```
gsub("[<>+]", "", "abc+def<ghi>xyz")
### [1] "abcdefghixyz"
```

Look for discussion of *character class* in `?regexp` .

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I've tried the following code: clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER <- gsub("[<>+]", "", "abc+def<ghi>xyz",clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER)

But it ended up turning every row to abcdefghixyz

Comment: That makes no sense "abc..." was sample input since the question did not (but should have) included input.  The first two arguments should be as in the answer and the third argument should be the input vector.  Please read `?gsub` carefully.

Comment: Sorry, as noted I am very new to R. Yes, I can see that that would not make sense.

I want to remove any instances of < + >, I do not wish to replace them with other text, just null them out.

It is possible I am using the wrong function, but I have used REGEX in SQL before and used it to remove characters.

The gsub description advises gsub(pattern, replacement, x,

In the following code `clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER <- gsub("[<>+]", "",clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER)` I have pattern, replacement of "" and specify the value, but it leaves the column as it was.

Comment: Copy and paste the code shown in the answer into your R session and you should get the same answer as shown there. Since you haven't provided a reproducible example it is up to you to figure out what is different about what you have versus what was presented.

Comment: Wiktor in the comments kindly identified the issue as being a unicode character, something I have not run into previously.

Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
gsub('[your_characters_to_match]+', '', vector)
```

should probably work.

Comment: Hello there, I've tried the following two instructions and both leave the rows as they were, no change:

`clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER = as.character(gsub('[<,+,>]+', '', clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER))`

 

`clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER = as.character(gsub('[<+>]+', '', clean$AGENT_REFERENCE_BROKER))`